# How can I specify password encryption strength in openssl_pkey_new?

Tags: php, cryptography, openssl, rsa

Using the PHP functions `openssl_pkey_new` and `openssl_pkey_export` to generate an RSA key, how can one ensure the toughest password protection?
e.g.

```
$conf = array (
    'digest_alg'       => 'sha256',
    'private_key_type' => OPENSSL_KEYTYPE_RSA,
    'private_key_bits' => 2048,
    'encrypt_key'      => true,
);
$keypair = openssl_pkey_new( $conf );
openssl_pkey_export( $keypair, $keyout, 'foopass', $conf );
```

Using openssl from the command line, I can specify tripledes like so:

```
 openssl genrsa -des3 -passout pass:foopass 2048
```

Comment: Encryption security is heavily related to what you're doing with it. Details are required.

Comment: I'm storing my private keys in a database and want to ensure that the password protection is strong enough that the database is useless if stolen.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As far as I know, specifying the `encrypt_key` as `true` in `$configargs` (like you did in your code example) already encrypts using Triple DES. If you check the output of `$keyout`, you will see:

```
-----BEGIN RSA PRIVATE KEY-----
Proc-Type: 4,ENCRYPTED
DEK-Info: DES-EDE3-CBC,6FDE8DC937CC1C27
```

This is true whether you use a `sha1`, `md5`, `sha256` or any other digests.

In other words, `'encrypt_key' => true` does exactly the same as `openssl genrsa -des3`.